# покупка платного аккаунта и работа с firebase

Tags: android, firebase, облако

Пишу приложение live-wallpaper на андроид с использованием FireBase.
Последовал вопрос:
У нас есть бесплатно аккаунт с ограниченным количеством данных для хранения данных, а также данных, которые пользователи могут скачать с сервера. 
Мы имеем следующие бесплатные мощности:

1. Realtime Database

   - GB stored
   - GB transferred
2. Storage

   - GB stored
   - GB transferred
   - Operations (uploads & downloads)

Представляем ситуацию, когда количество установок приложения будет >0. Соответственно количество трафика который пользователи будут использовать для скачивания обоев, будет больше чем нам доступно на бесплатном аккаунте. Так что нужно задуматься об увеличении объема данных, которые могут быть скачаны с хранилища.

Следовательно что именно из приведенных выше пунктов нужно увеличить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как не печально, то всё, так как будет много трафика, а где много трафика там и много stored нужно. Если у вас пользователи будут загружать в базу тоже фото, то вам нужно будет сильно увеличить stored, если только из вашей библиотеки, то только трафик.

`Я бы посоветовал брать Blaze Plan`

Прочитайте это здесь: https://firebase.google.com/pricing/?authuser=0

Удачи вам :)

Comment: У меня есть доступ к безлимитному хранилищу на Google Drive. Поэтому я думаю что подойдет вариант хранить обои на нем, а в FireBase прописать только ссылки на них. Получается что единственная нагрузка которая будет идти на сервер гугла это количество одновременных подключений.

Comment: Тогда вам нужно изучить `google drive rest api`. Я бы на вашем месте сделал свой сервер на Raspberry PI, только нужно постоянное подключение к интернету!